# handle widgets size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stack but I want to get first widget height and width ,then pass of their value to height and width of second widget in my stack.
how can I achieve this ?

```dart
Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/images/phonograph-record.png',
                              ),
                            ),
                            ClipOval(
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                height: firstWidgetHeight/2,
                                width: firstWidgetWidth/2,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                imageUrl: thisSongInfo.albumImageUrl,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
```

Comment: Since you have image in your assets, so you already know its `width` and `height` in logical pixels, you can use it directly. One more thing you can do, instead of using `AssetImage`, use `Image.asset` and give it fixed `width` and `height` and use this in your 2nd widget.

Comment: I think if I give it width and height , I get into trouble with different devices and also the height of this widget restricted because I use it inside an Expanded widget so I think the width and height in logical pixels is a dummy number . is it correct ?

Comment: I haven't tried logical pixels on my own personally, so I can't really comment on it. However, using `Image.asset` would work in your case when you provide `width` and `height` using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/height * someFraction`, this should solve the problem for different screen sizes.

Comment: excuse me , because I am almost new to flutter , I don't understand. what is someFraction and how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

`CachedNetworkImage` have a `placeholder` if you want that effect.

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    placeholder: (context, url) => Image(
                          image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/phonograph-record.png',
                          ),
                        ),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```